# Utilising AWS Cloudfront for domain which listens on non-443 port

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We have a `www.domain.com` which resolves to a AWS Load Balancer backed by AWS EC2 Nginx instance.

`www.domain.com:8888` proxies to a AWS backend web application.

`www.domain.com:443` serves static html from EC2's disk excepting:

- `/app/` path which proxies to a dynamic backend application running on an EC2
- 404 responses which also proxy to the same dynamic backend EC2 for custom error pages.

Objective: to be able to serve our static html directly from S3 storage under the domain `www.domain.com` (we currently sync the S3 static files down to the disk of the Nginx server).

Options considered:

- Cloudfront with a failover origin group will take care of the port 443 traffic nicely. But if we associate `www.domain.com` with cloudfront, obviously nothing will listen on `www.domain.com:8888`.
- If we have a Load Balancer providing the listeners for `www.domain.com` we can deal with dynamic traffic on ports 443 and 8888. But it's not obvious how to have S3 as a Load Balancer target group. I believe this could be possible with a VPC endpoint for S3. But could this deal with 404 failovers? (Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/hosting-internal-https-static-websites-with-alb-s3-and-privatelink/ )
- We embark on a project to move `www.domain.com:8888` traffic to `alt.domain.com:443` and then use option 1. However, as long as we want to preserve links to `www.domain.com:8888` I think we are barred from having cloudfront as the destination of `www.domain.com`.
- Have a frontend Nginx proxy which proxies 8888 traffic to a Load Balancer, and 443 traffic to cloudfront. This would negate many of the plus points of using Cloudfront by forcing client traffic through a proxy to get there. Plus we'd need to handle SSL termination via Lets Encrypt outside Amazon ACM.

Option 3 seems like the cleanest option, but would not happen quickly or easily.. so we are looking for alternatives.

Are there other options we should be considering?